# Как работает побитовый оператор XOR в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, битовые-операции, xor

Почему после 11100, выскакивает 420, а не 00100, но конечное значение (11000), всё равно соответствует первоначальному?

```js
var sir = 11000;
alert(sir);
var meg = 11100;
alert(meg);
var tun = sir ^ meg;
alert(tun);
alert(tun ^ meg);
```

Comment: А что не так? Вы взяли 2 десятичных числа. Сделали XOR и получили правильный результат. Двоичная запись числа в js производится другим способом, как и во многих других языках программирования, через `0b`

Comment: а в чем должна быть ошибка ил что вас смущает?

Comment: А как можно указать принадлежность числа к двоичной системе? Я попробовал поставить 0b перед числами, но произошёл их перевод в десятичную систему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы записываете 2 числа в десятичной системе счисления. Операция ^(XOR) производится над битами(!), которыми представлены эти 2 числа.
Т.е.

```
1100010 = 101010111110002
```

```
1110010 = 101011010111002
```

Применив к ним операцию ^ получим следующее:

```
          000001101001002 = 42010
```

"Но конечное значение (11000), всё равно соответствует первоначальному." - это одно из свойств операции XOR: `(a XOR b) XOR b = a`
Это скрытые тонкости программирования так сказать. Сам в своё время долго догонял что к чему и как.

Comment: А возможно как-нибудь указать, к какой системе исчисления принадлежит записанное число (в моём примере к двузначной)?

Comment: Да, есть способ - любое число, представленное в системе счисления, отличной от десятичной записывается в виде строки. Метод `toString()` - это то, что Вам нужно.

`Number(sir.toString(2));` - даст двоичное представление числа в переменной `sir`.
Но XOR над этим представлением все равно не сработает:)
Строка выше даст уже десятичное число и XOR будет работать с битами этого десятичного число. В итоге будет дичь

Comment: Чтобы применить XOR Вам, думаю, подойдет следующее                                                 
`(parseInt(sir, 2) ^ parseInt(meg, 2)).toString(2)`